# HTTP Request in AWS Lambda is not working / NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, get, alexa-skills-kit

i know, this topic was discussed very often. But these posts are either very old, or do not fix my problem. So i try it with opening a new (other) one.
I recently started making Alexa Skills. So now i managed to set up my AWS Lambda function with the help of (an also old) Tutorial. Everything worked fine in the first step.
So now i want to sent a GET Request to a website, just to get the status code. In the next step, Alexa should tell me this code- but thats a diffrent story.
So i tried to get the request done with many different code snippets- but nothing worked. After reading various posts, i understand that the code runs faster then the request can be executed. So the answer of the request does never show up in the logs. Which means, i cannot make use of it.

This is my current code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.session.new) {
      console.log("new session");
    }
    switch (event.request.type) {
      case "LaunchRequest":
        console.log("LAUNCH REQUEST");
        context.succeed(
          generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("This is a launch request", true), {}
          )
        )
        break;
      case "IntentRequest":
        console.log("INTENT REQUEST")
        switch (event.request.intent.name) {
          case "checkConnection":
            console.log("INTENT CHECK CONNECTION")
            const https = require('https')
            let url = "xxx/xxx/bc/alexa"
            exports.handler = async function(event) {
              console.log("async function")
              const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                https.get(url, (res) => {
                  resolve(res.statusCode)
                }).on('error', (e) => {
                  reject(Error(e))
                })
              })
              return promise
            }
            context.succeed(null, generateResponse(
              buildSpeechletResponse("server answered with code " + this.statusCode, true), {}));
            break;
        }
      case ("SessionEndedRequest"):
        console.log("SESSION ENEDED REQUEST")
        break;
      default:
        context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`);
        break;
    }
  }
  catch (error) { context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`) }
}
// Helpers
buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {
  console.log("buildSpeechletResponse");
  return {
    outputSpeech: {
      type: "PlainText",
      text: outputText
    },
    shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
  }
};
generateResponse = (speechletResponse, sessionAttributes) => {
  console.log("generateResponse")
  return {
    version: "1.0",
    sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
    response: speechletResponse
  }
};
```

If i test the code via the lambda test (including the JSON from Alexa to check connection), the log look like this.

- 14:48:14 START RequestId: c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 Version: $LATEST
- 14:48:14 2020-02-13T14:48:14.802Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO { version: '1.0', session: { new: true, sessionId: 'amzn1.echo-api.session.0a26e495-1085-44e0-83f3-13937d026c1b', application: { applicationId: 'amzn1.ask.skill.42b0dea7-952e-4695-a3d2-ab951c98ac9c' }, user: { userId: 'amzn1.ask.account.AHKG3FP33CDNS5PBKQESKQ73PAWMYTB7PRL4A2UGJTG77NOGSKKQBG5QNKVZ
- 14:48:14 2020-02-13T14:48:14.802Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO new session
- 14:48:14 2020-02-13T14:48:14.802Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO INTENT REQUEST
- 14:48:14 2020-02-13T14:48:14.802Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO INTENT CHECK CONNECTION
- 14:48:14 2020-02-13T14:48:14.964Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO buildSpeechletResponse
- 14:48:14 2020-02-13T14:48:14.964Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO generateResponse
- 14:48:15 2020-02-13T14:48:15.042Z c8790cd2-81c9-4b8e-98ac-91b2ae6493f6 INFO SESSION ENEDED REQUEST

So as far as i see, th code runs to "INTENT CHECK CONNECTION", but the log "async function" never shows up. So what happens here? Is the code skipped? How do i manage to get a working http request state of the art? (Sorry, if my post is not the "common way". It is also my first post)

Comment: can you show the full code. I think the problem is here `exports.handler = async function(event) {`

Comment: I added the full code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. The code i provided was nearly correct. The request function needed to be capsuled into another function. With minor adjustments, it worked with this code:

```
    // HTTP Request Function
function httpGet(options) {
  const https = require('https');
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let returnData = '';
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
        return reject(new Error(`${response.statusCode}: ${response.req.getHeader('host')} ${response.req.path}`));
      }
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(response.statusCode); //Fill response with status code
      });
      response.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
    request.end();
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your code  exports.handler = async function(event) {} is the cause
```

exports.handler is always in entry function in AWS lambda

I just remove this code

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.session.new) {
      console.log("new session");
    }
    switch (event.request.type) {
      case "LaunchRequest":
        console.log("LAUNCH REQUEST");
        context.succeed(
          generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("This is a launch request", true), {}
          )
        )
        break;
      case "IntentRequest":
        console.log("INTENT REQUEST")
        switch (event.request.intent.name) {
          case "checkConnection":
            console.log("INTENT CHECK CONNECTION")
            const https = require('https')
            let url = "xxx/xxx/bc/alexa"

                https.get(url, (res) => {
                   context.succeed(null, generateResponse(
              buildSpeechletResponse("server answered with code " + res.statusCode, true), {}));
                }).on('error', (e) => {
// handle error here
                  reject(Error(e))
                })
              })


            break;
        }
      case ("SessionEndedRequest"):
        console.log("SESSION ENEDED REQUEST")
        break;
      default:
        context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`);
        break;
    }
  }
  catch (error) { context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`) }
}
// Helpers
buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {
  console.log("buildSpeechletResponse");
  return {
    outputSpeech: {
      type: "PlainText",
      text: outputText
    },
    shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
  }
};
generateResponse = (speechletResponse, sessionAttributes) => {
  console.log("generateResponse")
  return {
    version: "1.0",
    sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
    response: speechletResponse
  }
};
```

Comment: So you mean, i do not need to write the "exports.handler = async function(event) {}" line? or do i need to change mine into yours? What happens with the " => {" after the arguments?

Comment: Just use my code into your code  after Arrow function => it send response using context.success

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not get ir right now. I changed my "exports.handler=async(event, context, callback)" into your "exports.handler=async(event)". After that i changed the body of case "IntentRequest" into your code. Now i got a undefined context. I am sure i misunderstood something. Can you please explain me what exactly to do? And what the problem is/was? Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that nothing changed. The log file looks like this. I inserted a "console.log("get request") inside the function, to see it gets executed.:

2020-02-13T23:11:34.454Z 9bb723dd-086d- INFO new session
2020-02-13T23:11:34.454Z 9bb723dd-086d- INFO INTENT REQUEST
2020-02-13T23:11:34.454Z 9bb723dd-086d- INFO INTENT CHECK CONNECTION
END RequestId: 9bb723dd-086d-400f-b143-9b52880fbe88
REPORT RequestId: 9bb723dd-086d-400f-b143-9b52880fbe88 Duration: 553.76 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB Init Duration: 117.19 ms